# Refine search results control

Tags: sharepoint, moss, moss2007enterprisesearch

I am using People Search Core Results PageLayout for my People Search WebPart.
By default when you search it gives an option of Refine your search.
As I observe its getting those options from a Control.
<SEARCHWC:RefineSearchResults runat="server" Title="<%$Resources:sps,RefineByTitle%>" SearchProperty="JobTitle"/>
I tried to edit the page layout and added my property in the Title value but it throw a error.
<SEARCHWC:RefineSearchResults runat="server" Title="<%$Resources:sps,RefineBymyProperty%>" SearchProperty="myProperty"/>
Can any one help me how to add myproperty on the page.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the RefineSeachResults control is sealed in Moss 2007 but in SharePoint 2010 its extendable.
That is the reason you can't find it in the control templates even though it represents to be as user control.
To add you propoerty for example in my case to show "myProperty" I have kept that inline and it worked.
<SEARCHWC:RefineSearchResults runat="server" Title="RefineBy myProperty" SearchProperty="myProperty"/>
If you have scenario where you want extra functionality other that OOB then the only option is write custom control.
Hope this might help someone.
Thanks